# can't access to database in mySql workbench?

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

when i try to access workbench database i get this error
SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 60500

this is code

```
Future connectToDb() async {
    // var rng = Random();
    final conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        db: 'sql_workbench',
        password: '12345678a@',
    ),
    ).then((value) {
      print("value");
    });


  }
```

[image: this is the connection prosperities]

Comment: can you drop the complete error code? hit on test connection button to see if you are connected first. No blocked port.

Comment: but how to make sure that port is not blocked?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 50308
E/flutter ( 2549): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:35)
E/flutter ( 2549): #1      _NativeSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:948:12)
E/flutter ( 2549): #2      _RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1805:26)
E/flutter ( 2549): #3      RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:21:23)

Comment: Click the test connection button to make sure you are connected before testing with it flutter

Comment: i checked it and it's connected but when i check it in flutter gives me this error message